# Pass Ruby Array via Ajax and Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working on a Rails project in which I have a somewhat of an odd situation where I need to load a template (via ajax) into an existing page and populate the template with values from a Ruby array sent from that page. Here's my example:

Article Page:

```
<div class="article"></div>

<% @article = my_article_array.to_json %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              data: { 'article' : '<%= @article %> }, 
              url: '/articles/show',
                  success: function(result) {
                     $(".article").html(result);
                  }
            });
     });   
</script>
```

Controller:

```
def show
   @article = JSON.parse(params[:article])
   redner :template => false
end
```

Template:

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
```

This results in a Rails error: "JSON.parse unexpected token error".

I've tried dozens of different scenarios, but converting the array to JSON first then decoding it once passed along seemed to make the most sense. Regardless, none of my attempts have worked.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us the JSON sent to your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSON to transport you data to the page and back again shouldn't be a problem. If your actual code is anywhere near as messy and buggy as your example then you likely just have a few bugs to squash and are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code used above was merely excepts for the sake of demonstrating the problem. However, it seems rails performs some kind of character escaping when transporting the JSON array and as a result I end up with &lt's and other entities, thus reconstructing the transferred array returns an error. Is this normal Rails (v3.0.5) behavior?

Comment: @two2twelve If you have data in a Ruby array and you want that in json without the escaping.. just do this - some_array.to_json.html_safe